# How do i use different CSS options for different pages using gmaps4rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I want to have different size maps on differernt pages...but i can't see to figure it out. When I disable css, the whole map disappears.

```
<%= gmaps({ map_options: {
                                zoom: 8,
                                auto_zoom: false },
                            markers: { data: @json } },
                            enable_css: false) %>
```

and then i put CSS around it:

```
<div id="sidebar">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 294px; height: 370px; position: relative">
                <%= gmaps({ map_options: {
                                zoom: 8,
                                auto_zoom: false },
                            markers: { data: @json } },
                            enable_css: false) %>
            </div>
        </div>
```

but that makes the map disappear. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a [look at the wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/%28Multiple%29-Maps) (or at the html page). The html generated is by default:

```
<div class="map_container"> 
  <div id="map" class="gmaps4rails_map"></div> 
</div>
```

So if you want to style, simply:

- edit or disable gmaps4rails css
- style the classes/id presented above, no need to add extra markup

Comment: I did that...but what if I want to have different size maps for different pages on my site? There's only one div available...right?

Comment: You can change the class and id by passing options within the helper. See wiki